# Typed User Search on a Dictionary (Asking for direction/techniques on how to improve efficiency of what I already have)

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, search, user-input

So I've built out a Database that contains a data table.
There are approximately 100,000 lines in this table.
Some more details of the table:

1. Column 1: Contains 30 Unique values (categories)
2. Column 2: Contains 50 Unique values (categories)
3. Column 3: Contains 200 Unique values (categories)
4. Column 1, 2 and 3 are independent of each other so any combination of the unique values can be found on any given line item of the data table.
5. Column 4: Each line item value is different with almost no repetition of values.
6. All data table columns have an equal number of line items.

One of the uses for this table is to allow users to type a word (or series of words separated by spaces " ") that will then be used to search through the data table, returning all rows that have column values that are similar matches to the user typed search term(s). The search is performed on the values of Columns 1, 2, 3, and 4.

I query the data table at startup and the values are returned as a dictionary outlined below. (I built my app on anvil works so technically 'result' is a [lazy search iterator](https://anvil.works/docs/data-tables/data-tables-in-code#searching-simple-objects))

```
result = {'column1': [value0,..., valueN], 'column2': [string,..., stringN], ect.}
```

Currently my search method is as follows (this is the slow part):

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from operator import itemgetter

def similarity_sort(search_term, result):
    search_terms = search_term.split()
    if len(search_terms) > 1:
        search_terms.append(search_term)
    temp = []
    sorted_result = []

    for index in range(len(result['column1'])):
        check_count = 0
        overall = 0
        for term in search_terms:
            a = perform_check(term, result['column1'][index])
            b = perform_check(term, result['column2'][index])
            c = perform_check(term, result['column3'][index])
            d = perform_check(term, result['column4'][index])
            overall += sum([a, b, c, d])
            check_count += 4
        overall /= check_count
        temp.append([index, overall])
    temp.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    for x in temp:
        if x[1] > 0.4:
            sorted_result.append(x[0])
    return sorted_result

def perform_check(term, row_value):
    if term.lower() == row_value.lower():
        check_ratio = 2
    else:
        check_ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, term.lower(), row_value).quick_ratio()
    return check_ratio
```

I'm worried this search won't scale well when the table starts to get bigger.

I'm looking for a method to structure the data that enables me to perform fast searches on the entire table with the specifications stated above. Any techniques (literally anything at all) you think would be useful for me to look into would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I've been considering implementing an inverted index structure. This would be a data table that contains a word and the rows its contained in (in the data table described above). Something like:

Term | Row ID (list)

Where I would check for matches between the search terms and the term column of the inverted index table and then pull row ID's for any matches.

This would be an increase in efficiency but since there are a lot of different words this would still be quite a large table and iterating over it when a user types a search might only have marginal improvements.

I've also been considering a Hash Table where rows will be bucketed based on their unique values. Then the search will be performed on the buckets, if a match is made the entire bucket is returned.

Not sure which would be best or if I'm missing another structure that would be more suitable. Thank you for your time!